# The differences between procedures with and without brackets?

Tags: scheme, lisp

```
(define (procedere1) (lambda () 2))
(define procedure2 (lambda () 2))
```

They both can be compiled. But I am confused about the difference between above two procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is a procedure that returns a procedure. The second one is a procedure that returns the number 2.

In particular, the first one is equivalent to the following:

```
(define procedure1
  (lambda ()
    (lambda () 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In general

```
(define (name arg1 arg2 arg3 ...)
  body)
```

is shorthand for

```
(define name
  (lambda (arg1 arg2 arg3 ...) 
    body))
```